# How do I attach to window in webpack to make it available in browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I can attach to window in my `entry.ts` file, but when it builds my bundle it wraps the attachment, and prevents it from attaching in the actual browser.

```
import "bootstrap";

declare var $: any
declare const window: Window
(<any> window).$ = (<any> window).jQuery = $;
```

In my `entry.ts` file I can access jQuery via `$` or `jQuery`, but not from my browser console or separate scripts I include via tags.

webpack:

```
plugins: ([
    // make sure we allow any jquery usages outside of our webpack modules
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    }),
```

I can use `expose-loader` but that exposes a version of jQuery I can't modify within my module (ie, by loading bootstrap and attaching `popover()` to jQuery).